# Need help calling a Haskell function whose arguments involves types which themselves take args

Tags: haskell

Sorry if the title is ambiguous, essentially I have the following data type declarations:

```
type Domino = (Integer, Integer)
type Hand = [Domino]
type Board = [Domino]
type DomsPlayer = Hand -> Board -> (Domino, End)
type Score = (Integer, String)
```

and a function:

```
playDomsRound :: DomsPlayer -> DomsPlayer -> Int -> (Score, Score)
```

how do I go about calling the playDomsRound function?

Comment: It's appears as though you just need to pass it an Int, and two functions, each that take a Hand and a Board. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Cardinal Rule of Typed Application* in Haskell is, very simply,

```
f    :: a  -> b   ===
f (x :: a) :: b
```

Thus, in your case,

```
playDomsRound    :: DomsPlayer     -> DomsPlayer     -> Int  -> (Score, Score)   ===
playDomsRound (p :: DomsPlayer)    :: DomsPlayer     -> Int  -> (Score, Score)   ===
playDomsRound (p :: DomsPlayer) (q :: DomsPlayer)    :: Int  -> (Score, Score)   ===
playDomsRound (p :: DomsPlayer) (q :: DomsPlayer) (i :: Int) :: (Score, Score)
```

and you can write any of the above in your code.

Any expression which has a type, can appear in your code.

Since you've defined

```
type DomsPlayer = Hand -> Board -> (Domino, End)
```

the type `DomsPlayer` is the same as the type `Hand -> Board -> (Domino, End)`. This is what your `playDomsRound` expects: a function. Not yet applied to any of the arguments that *it* expects. Just a function.